# Shiloysh mayoys, sheesheem vichawmaysh (365) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

Every number has a special significance in the Torah

It's known that 365 corresponds to the number of "don't do", otherwise known as "negative" mitzvos (commandments) as well as the 365 "sinews" of the human body (which also metaphorically correspond to the 365 "sinews" of Hashem, so to speak (kawvyachoyl), a metaphor for the negative mitzvos) as well as the 365 days it the solar year (see rambam, introduction), but I was wondering what other, if any, significance does the number 365 have in the Torah

Blessings and success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bereishis 5:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.5.23?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0) - Chanoch lived for 365 years.